# Failed to save data in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

when trying to save in my Mongo database, I can't record the data, to the point of connection with the DB is fine but then it doesn't save the data.
Today is my first day with Mongo, it may be that something is wrongly configured.

**My controller**

```
exports.nuevoCliente = async (req, res, next) => {
    // console.log(req.body);

    const paciente = new Paciente(req.body);
    try {
        await paciente.save();
        res.json({ mensaje : 'El cliente se agregó correctamente'}); 
        console.log(paciente);

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        next();
    }
}
```

**When I run:**

```
console.log(paciente);
```

Result = __v: 0

[image]

**Model:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const pacientesSchema = new Schema({
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
    },
    propietario: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    fecha: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    telefono: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    hora: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    sintomas: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Paciente', pacientesSchema);
```

**Routes**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
// Importar el controlador
const pacienteController = require('../controllers/pacienteControllers');

module.exports = function() {

    // router.get('/', () => {
    //     console.log('en home');

    // });

    // Agrega nuevos pacientes via POST
    router.post('/pacientes',
        pacienteController.nuevoCliente
    );

    return router;
}
```

**And the index:**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const routes = require('./routes');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Crear el servidor
const app = express();


// Conectar con MongoDB
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/veterinaria', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true,
    useFindAndModify:false
});

// Habilitar el body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// Habilitar Routing
app.use('/', routes())


// Puerto y Arrancar
app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Servidor funcionando')
})
```

***A screenshot of the configuration in atlas***

[image]

Thanks friends.

Comment: Do you connect localhost? `mongodb://localhost/veterinaria` Make sure your patient is stored in localhost, not remote MongoDB server

Comment: yes in localhost. how i cant do this??

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is in the AWAIT used at saving point.
Try to use:

```
paciente.save(function (err, saved) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } 
    else {  
       console.log(saved); 
       res.json({ mensaje : 'El cliente se agregó correctamente'}); 
    }
}
```

Anyway to check if it's really saved, you can connect to mongo trough shell
   https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongo-shell/ and query manually the collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.nuevoCliente = async (req, res, next) => {
    // console.log(req.body);

    // Crear Objeto de paciente con datos de req.body
    const paciente = new Paciente(req.body);

    paciente.save(function (err, saved) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } 
        else {  
           console.log(saved); 
           res.json({ mensaje : 'El cliente se agregó correctamente'}); 
        }
    }
    )
}
```

Many thanks for your response

Comment: Is this an answer or something you wanted to say to someone ?

Answer (score -1):

According to your code, you have connected your local mongo then 
You can check via MongoDB log in your terminal or mongo shell.

```
logfile path is - /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check mongo log

Comment: You can check and see that what is going on in your mongo.

Comment: I have updated and posted an image of the result. You have it up.
Thank you very much for your great help.

Comment: Go through the path.

Comment: If you will see via tail -100f mongo.log

Comment: Then you can see everything which query is running hitting saving data all.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but I don't understand what I have to do.
Yes you can specify a little more. Thanks a lot for your patience

Comment: Did you find it?

Comment: Hi Ankit, It has been a beginner's mistake with the link between compass and atlas.
Compass offered me one that was not worth recording data, it only served to connect create DB and collections, but not record data in the collection.
Thank you very much for your interest, hopefully one day I can be useful.
Greetings